# How to check for nested keys assertion in chai library?

Tags: javascript, chai

I am writing some simple unit tests with the chai assertion library. I am writing a test for loading financial data from stock market tickers.

The function will go through the list of tickers and add their data to an object called "data" which will contain keys identified by the respective stock market tickers. Each of these keys will store their respective financial data.

Here is the code for the same

```
it('adds a new map with loaded data where the key is the ticker symbol after API request', () => {
        const state = Map();
        const tickers = List.of('AAPL', 'TSLA', 'GOOGL', 'FB');
        const nextState = loadAPIData(state, tickers);

        expect(nextState).to.equal(fromJS({
            tickers: ['AAPL', 'TSLA', 'GOOGL', 'FB']
        }, data: {
            AAPL: {
                //data for AAPL goes here
            }, 
            TSLA: {
                //data for TSLA goes here
            }, 
            GOOGL: {
                //data for GOOGL goes here
            },
            FB: {
                //data for FB goes here
            }
        }));
    })
```

Now, my question is how do I check to see that the keys containing the various stock market tickers have been added to the data object and the data object itself has been created without knowing what kind of data is being loaded by the API? All I want to know is that data was loaded and added to the respective keys.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
expect(nextState).to.deep.equal(...)
```

Reference http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_equal